# How should I use Scallion to hash .onion domains on Windows 7?

Tags: onion-routing

For setting up a Tor hidden service, I need a good .onion URL, I do not want to trust anyone else with generating that pair of public and private key and then hand them to me.

I have downloaded scallion binaries on Windows 7, but do not know how to run it on Windows 7 and hash custom .onion domains?

Do you have any idea how this works?

Comment: Have you read the README? https://github.com/lachesis/scallion/blob/gpg/README.md

Comment: i read it now, i think i should run it with visual studio express. right?

Answer (score 2):

If you've downloaded the Windows binaries - which is what you have done - you can run the executable directly.

If you had downloaded the source, you would have needed to build using VS Express, as per the [README](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion/blob/gpg/README.md).

So, once you've downloaded the binaries:

- Unzip the `.zip` file containing the pre-built files.
- Open a command prompt by running `cmd`.
- Navigate to the location where your unzipped directory is located.
- If you run `scallion.exe` either with the `-h` option, or with no options at all, you'll be given the help details. Have a read of this to familiarise yourself with the main options you can pass to the executable.

The most basic operation is to just pass the string you want to include in your .onion address:

`C:\(path_to_dir)> scallion.exe string`

The Usage section of the README provides further examples.

If you hit any problems - for example, you get an error message complaining about missing DLLs - have a look at the Dependencies section of the README.